# Git Flow Feature branch best practice

Tags: git-flow

Have branched off develop for two features

- develop -> featureA
- develop -> featureB

Feature A is nearly finished in terms of development but is on hold for a bit while the product owner does some research.

Developer started featureB but needs a small amount of core code from feature A.

What is the best practice in this case? I cannot assume that featureA and B would be in the same release.

Cheers

Comment: Try cherry pick from Feature A to Feature B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very similar (yet not exactly the same) problem - including my answer - can be found in [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63789672/do-not-release-all-feature-already-merged-into-dev-branch/63958233#63958233).

Regarding your problem your should use [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) since you do not want to use all of `featureA` yet.