# Do not release all feature already merged into dev branch

Tags: git-flow

[image]

We have 2 features `A` and `B` already merged into `dev` branch, branch `dev` using for test environment and both 2 features are tested. Now we just want to release only feature `A`, how to do it ? Did our git flow is wroong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `git-flow` looks fine so far. It is simply not meant to be used to release `develop` partially.

Whatever gets merged onto `develop` is meant to be released.

Here are some solutions you could use:

(1) Do not merge (or better don't even start working on it) a feature until you want to release it.

(2) If you want to merge unfinished features add a feature toggle to easily turn on and off whatever is on `develop`.
Heads-up: not everyone thinks this is good software design - me included. But for the sake of completeness I wanted to mention it.

(3) Also not a good approach but technically possible: Revert the features you don't want to release on your `release` branch. This might be your only option now if you don't want to re-write the commit history (which you should not).

(4) Create a new `release` branch starting at the commit just before feature `B` was merged in and `cherry-pick` feature `A` into that `release` branch.